# How to get the path of the file from source root in java?

Tags: java, file, path, relative-path

I have a file in java under the `src` folder, I want to get its path at runtime relative to the source folder.
For example-

```
myProject
  -- src
    -- packageOne
      -- SomeFile.java
```

I would like to have the result `packageOne/SomeFile.java`. I couldn't find a way, I tried `getPath()`, `getAbsoultePath()` and every similar method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to construct a relative path. AFAIK there is no ready function to use.

Given that you have one of the ancestor nodes (src) and you have SomeFile.java, the following code might work but I did not try...

```
File src = new File("...");
File somefile = new File("...");

String relpath = somefile.getName();
File cursor = somefile.getParentFile();
while (!cursor.getAbsolutePath().equals(src.getAbsolutePath()) {
  somefile = cursor.getName() + File.pathSeparator + somefile;
}
System.out.println("relative path: "+relpath);
```